# Change cursor type on body while file downloading prepares

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change cursor type while file is preparing for user on server (about 5~ seconds). That is not work like this:

```
    $("#toolbuttonexcelfile").on("click", function (e) {
        var fileUrl = "hereIsMyFileUrl";           
        $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
        window.location.href = fileUrl;
        $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
    });
```

Comment: @hutchbat Looks like no events executes after windows.location.href change

Comment: @Sibway, that's true. My suggestion was for the page being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").css("cursor", "progress");

$( window ).load(function() {
($("body").css("cursor", "auto");
});
```

Comment: Sometimes file can be prepared 10 seconds, sometimes 1 second :) Here is no another way to do this? It is necessary to use timeout with average value?

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti document.ready and window.load is not executing for me after file download. I'v got this message in console: "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:"